# How to set the username on the LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL with python-social-auth?

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I'm working on a project and I'm using python-social-auth to login with Facebook and Twitter.

I want the `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` to go to a url with the username like this:

```
url(r'^(?P<username>\w+)/$', UserProfileView.as_view(), name='user-profile'),
```

I have been reading the documents but don't really know what would be the best way to do this. Does anyone have any advice if I should overwrite the `done` function? Or what is the best way to do it?

I'm using `django==1.6` and `python-social-auth==0.1.21`.

Comment: I would use a URL scheme like this: `/profile/username` = show the profile page of specific user, `/profile` = show my own profile page. This way you won't need to include the username in the redirect, you could use the same url for all users.

Comment: URL settings aren't callable, you can create your own `strategy` that overrides the setting gathering method and does some magic in the case of `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`. If you really need the name there I would create a simple view `/profile` that will redirect the user to `/profile/<username>`.

Comment: Thanks guys! I ended up doing what you mentioned @omab from profile redirect to profile/<username>